# preloading image on image tab gallery

Tags: javascript, css, gallery

followed the tutorial from w3 on the image tab gallery (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_img_gallery.asp).  On their own page the first image preloads when you refresh/enter page.  But in their tutorial code it doesn't.  I've researched asked and written some code to figure it out but so far no luck.

Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  I'm not sure where to call the javascript function in the main part of the code to actually display the image from the javascript at the end of the page.  My code below.  Thanks so much for any help.

MsKazza

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>College Hoodie - leavershoodies.ie</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- jQuery 1.8 or later, 33 KB -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'gothambook';
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column_images {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column_images img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left:17px;
}

.column_images img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left:17px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row_images:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container */
.container2 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width:350px;
  text-align:center;
/* background-color: #5e5e5e; */
}

/* Expanding image text */
#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 40%;
  color: #5e5e5e;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Closable button inside the expanded image */
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php

$product_id = $_GET['recordID'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_code = '$product_id'";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
?>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10px;">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
<div class="container2">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=none"; class="closebtn" ></span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="height:450px;"><br /><br />
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
<div class="row_images">
  <div class="column_images">
    <img src="images/products/<?php echo $row['img1']; ?>" alt="" style="height:100px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column_images">
    <img src="images/products/<?php echo $row['img2']; ?>" alt="" style="height:100px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column_images">
    <img src="images/products/<?php echo $row['img3']; ?>" alt="" style="height:100px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
<div class="column_images">
  <img src="images/products/<?php echo $row['img4']; ?>" alt="" style="height:100px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
</div>

</div>

</div> <!-- end of left 5 column -->
<div class="col-8">
<h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></h1>
<br />
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3"><h5>Description</h></div>
<div class="col">
<?php echo $row['description']; ?>

</div>
</div> <!-- /row --><br />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3"><h5>Specification</h></div>
<div class="col">
<?php echo $row['specification']; ?>
</div>
</div> <!-- /row --><br />

<div class="row">
<div class="col-3"><h5>Available Sizes</h></div>
<div class="col">
XS - S - M - L - XL - XXL - 3XL
</div>
</div> <!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- desc container -->
<br /><br />
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM colours WHERE product_id = '$product_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo '
  <div style="float:left; width:55px; text-align:center;">
    <label class="container">
      <img src="images/products/pakshots/'.$row["filename"].'" alt="'.$row["colour_name"].'" style="width:50px" onclick="myFunction(this);">
      <br /><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="colour">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
';

}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div> <!-- end of main content column -->
</div> <!-- end of main content row -->
</div> <!-- end of main container -->


<hr>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center col-md-6 col-12">
          <h3>More Information</h3>
          <p>If your not quite sure yet and would like to discuss further please either call us, request a call back, or get a quote on this product.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#" role="button">GET QUOTE</a>
          <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" href="#" role="button">REQUEST CALL BACK</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center col-md-6 col-12">
          <h3>Loving it? Lets go!</h3>
          <p>If you've made your choice and this is the top for you and yours, please select the colour you would like and click 'Choose this top'.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">REGISTER / LOGIN</a>
          <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="#" role="button">CHOOSE THIS TOP</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<br /><br />
<?php } ?>


          <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js"></script>

<script>

function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}

function initMainImg() {
  var img = document.getElementsByClassName("column_images")[0].childNodes[0];
  myFunction(img);
}


</script>

  </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I see it's been months that you've asked this and because I've had the same issue and found an (possible) answer, I still want to add it to this post.

In your code add after `<div class="row_images">` and before `<div class="column_images">` the following:

```
<img id="expandedImg" style="width: 100%" src="*location of your image*">
```

Worked for me!
p.s. *location of your image* shouldn't be copied but refer to an image of yours